# Tune WebGL application rendering latency on Linux

Tags: linux, webgl, low-latency

I wonder how to reduce the rendering latency of my WebGL application on Linux.

I am using chromium-browser for rendering, as it seems to achieve fastest framerates for simple WebGL graphics. But I guess a browser is somewhat more complex than a simple fullscreen SDL / OpenGL window. Does the browser add a lot of latency? Or the window manager?

It seems for me using a non-compositing window manager like `openbox` in favor of for example `compiz` (like Ubuntus Unity would use) improves latency slightly.

Are there any other classic bottlenecks I can address?

Comment: Maybe try different browsers, and compare them.